# Group By function using Spring Data

Tags: mysql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a MySQL database, and I intend to implement a `Group By` query using Spring Data. (I'm really new to Spring Data)

i.e.

```
 Select Department, Count(*) From Employee Group By Department.
```

So far I've seen a lot of solutions here using MongoDb, but nothing on MySQL. I know you can use `@Query` annotation, but is there any other way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For specifying queries with Spring Data you have the following options:

1. Use one of the methods in the predefined interfaces like `CrudRepository` or `JpaRepository`. None of those does any grouping by.
2. Use [Query Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods) where the name of the method defines the query. There is no keyword for `group by` either.
3. Use a `@Query` annotation. This works, but you want an alternative.
4. You can write a [custom implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations). But why would you if you can achieve the same with the `@Query` annotation?

**While there is technically an alternative, you probably want to use `@Query` in this case.**